# BDD/ Test driven design in functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, tdd, bdd, property-based-testing

I am reading the "Test-Driven Development By Example" [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/d/cka/Test-Driven-Development-Addison-Wesley-Signature-Kent-Beck/0321146530) by Kent Beck (pdf available [here](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2003-04/W/3311/sectionM/case_studies/money/KentBeck_TDD_byexample.pdf)) in which he discusses the **multi-currency money** problem and designs a solution step by step, by introducing tests and consequently specifying the public methods for its classes and repeatedly refactoring to accommodate new tests/behaviours.

He starts by having `Franc` and `Dollar` classes. Having then contemplated on the interface of these classes and having looked at the code and spotted duplication, he refactors the two classes to be both derived from a `Money` class.

Couple of tests later, he realises `Franc` and `Dollar` do not really make sense as classes and introduces a `currency` string for the money and finally when it gets to summing monies in different currencies, he comes up with a super class of the `Money` class called `expression` which simplifies the support for additional operations on Money, such as summing different currencies.

To sum up, in my understanding, It is the **behaviours** and the **test expectation of objects** that guides the design process in TDD. My question is, since functional programming has less focus on objects and is more typeclass/trait oriented, does this mean that such **test driven design** practices are not really appropriate in the functional style? Can [property-driven testing](http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/04/property-based-testing-what-is-it.html) be considered to play a similar role in the design process with the functional style?

**Edit:**

In property based testing, one would introduce properties for methods, that should hold regardless of the implementation of a given method.
In normal testing, the most important property that is verified, is the correctness of the implementation. As sisyphus [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710547/5037033), there is the question of where the a-priori knowledge of the assertion arguments comes from, so checking for correctness does not necessarily give us the full picture.

There are other properties that paying attention to them, could be very enlightening. As an example, if I were to write a sort function and have `sortedList=mySort(myList)`, regardless of the implementation, I would like `sortedList` and `myList` to have the same length. If not, I probably have done something completely wrong, even though the test might work perfectly for all those other cases.

As another example, a function `MaxElement(list)` that returns `Option[int]` and takes a list of integers as input, should always return Some[int], if `list` is non empty.

To check these properties, one would write a customised generator for the input to these methods and then ask the test framework to generate enough input instances and test the property to guarantee a near certainty of its validity. In the case of money problem for instance, a generator could be written that would produce sub classes of money of various types and check them for equality, which would automatically bring to light, the need for considering some of those equality tests that Beck writes explicitly.

To rephrase the question, I am interested to know if the reason he made the natural mistake of having explicit classes for `Franc` and `Dollar`-which he later realised, when he noticed the duplicated implementation of certain methods in both classes- strongly related to the Object orientation approach in modelling systems. Can it be said that functional programming needs less of this *iterative design process*, simply because it doesn't start by objects and does functional decomposition instead. Or seeing the problem from another angle, does testing ever lead to changing the design of a system, in the functional style?

Comment: I would be curious to know your thoughts on this question 6 years later. I program in both paradigms and my thought process is very different. In FP I have this tendency to want to prove correctness of components because I work with sound abstractions and the type system guaranties that they can be safely composed, so it's an inside out approach, whereas in OO everything is ad hoc, so I am only interested in the observable behaviour. That difference only impacts unit tests though. I use BDD for acceptance tests because they test business requirements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, 'behaviour' is all that anybody **really** cares about - whether you're a user, a tester, a dev, a product owner, a sales person, a ...

What Kent Beck is doing is saying that we should be writing tests which

- demonstrate what is most important
- in the form which is most important
- to the people who are most likely to use the software under test.

So, in TDD Explained he's largely talking to library developers. His users are also developers - they're using a library involving Money interaction. And his use cases are what those developers can (or want to) do with that library.

He works with an object oriented language and so he comes up with an OO approach to resolve those three objectives as well as he can. If he'd started with a pure functional language he'd have come up with a pure functional decomposition. Either way you'd end up with an API which was useable and which I (as an application developer) could trust in my application.

The real point which Beck is trying to make is that tests should focus on *interaction* (or api, or interface) rather than *state* (fields , properties). State is related to implementation concerns, and which changes any time you change the implementation, whereas behaviour is related to what your users want and which is (generally) not as changeable between releases.

There is often a difference between a pure-functional and pure-OO API to approaches but Beck's approach to either is actually the same - what we care about is what happens when the user says 'if I have 20 USD then how many EUR does that equal'?

EDIT:

So, in terms of 'property-based development' a 'property' is a specification of how a method should return its values. To do that confidently, you often need to have a full implementation of the algorithm itself. And in those cases your test code needs to be able to do the thing which the production code does. That's fine from a precondition sense because it means that your tests are just a form of parameterised test, but it leads to a bootstrap problem - how do you ensure that your test implementation is correct? Either you've already got one (so you should use that in production) or you need to build one (so... how do you get that...).

Now, there are *some* types of tests (for some types of thing) which are easier to verify rather than by being parameterised by an algorithm. It's certainly true for some of the more NP type algorithms (e.g. Travelling Salesman Problem).

But ultimately it doesn't matter from a Functional vs. Object Oriented perspective. Whether you use an existing method to decide on correctness of your object's method or whether you use a valuable set of test examples to give you confidence is not too important. You can *still* bring an OO or an FP perspective to bear.

So here's the thing - TDD (a la Beck) and your notion of BDD are *both* about thinking about important aspects of the problem-solution space which 
allow the implementation algorithm to be better. They *both* ask you to focus on what are *valuable* examples (or discontinuities).

Comment: Very good summary of Beck's case. Not sure if I understood your conclusion. I guess I should have been more specific about my terminology. By "property-based" I really meant the generator driven property based testing, so to me a "property", is a property about the relation between the input and the output of a method. In my brief exposure to generator-driven testing, I have found that generators in their generality, often make you think about the assumptions you might be making about an input, which might have made you forget about the odd cases.

Comment: In the case of equality checks for money of the same currency for example, your generators make you think of the need to have a currency identifier which is essentially the same thing that happened in Beck's approach. I am not so clear if we can find equivalences in the case of the requirements for summing money for example. To me it feels like in functional programming, from the start, you would do a functional decomposition and `expression` would come in from early on and not exactly be a result of writing requirements in the form of public functions, as it happened in Beck's book. thoughts?

Comment: @ShS sorry, my bad, I've tried to edit to more adequately cover your question. I hope, anyway ;)

Comment: thanks! I have added an Edit which should hopefully make it clearer what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of opinion, which is better. This or that.

My take is that there isn't anything contradicting in using Behaviour-Driven Development, BDD, to drive out a system developed using functional programming language or an object oriented programming language. At the end of the day, a system has behaviour no matter how it is implemented.

Using property-driven development may or may not be a good complement. I guess it depends on the use case. I have a hard time understanding how I should use property-based testing for a business process. This drives me to the conclusion that there are cases where I don't see how you can use property-based testing while I at the same time can see a use for BDD.

As usual, it depends.

Comment: please refer to my comment on Sisyphus' reply. To me a "property" is a relationship between input and output. Isn't that what business wants: to guarantee that the whatever implementation you have, it doesn't assume something about the input which is not necessarily the case?